# Calling a function with if statments

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a function that is checking if anny textfield-element in the HTML containing the class "txt" has changed value sence the page last loaded. If anny text has been changed the function should return true in the if statement, otherwise false. However im only getting false. What im i doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<h3>Handlartext1...</h3>
<textarea class="txt">Hejsan</textarea><br/><br />

<h3>Handlartext2...</h3>
<textarea class="txt">Hejsan</textarea><br/><br />

<h3>Handlartext3...</h3>
<textarea class="txt">Hejsan</textarea><br/><br />

<input id="btnClick" type="button" value="Save changes" />
```

Script:

```
$('#btnClick').on("click",function() {
    if(CheckTextChange()) {
        alert('TRUE');
    }
    else {
        alert('FALSE');
    }    
})


function CheckTextChange () {
var previousVal = $(".txt").get(0).defaultValue, currentVal = $(this).text();
//Checks if values have changed in elements containing class="txt" 
$('.txt').each(function() {
       //alert( $(this).text()); //or $(this).text();

       if (currentVal != previousVal) {          
           return true;
       } 
       else {
           return false;
       }
    }) 
}
```

Comment: your function returns nothing (undefined) - which is falsey - you need to totally rewrite CheckTextChange

Comment: you do `return` from _each_ callback, instead of _CheckTextChange_ function

Comment: I think you might need to define your previous and current within your each. Isn't that what you're going for? See if any of them have changed?

Comment: also **note:** in doc: _You can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning false._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CheckTextChange function has a couple of issues:

1. it will only ever check the first value
2. It doesn't get the text properly

You could change it to something like this:

```
function CheckTextChange() {

    //Checks if values have changed in elements containing class="txt" 
    var isChanged = false;
    $('.txt').each(function () {
        var previousVal = $(this).get(0).defaultValue,
            currentVal = $(this).val();
        //alert( $(this).text()); //or $(this).text();

        if (currentVal != previousVal) {
            isChanged = true;
        }
    });

    return isChanged;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zar68zjh/)

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems with your code. For example, when you read `text()` of `$(this)`, your function doesn't know what `this` is. Without actually solving your problem, perhaps this will lead you in the right direction:
http://jsfiddle.net/6ymxw4mg/

```
$('#btnClick').on("click", function () {
    CheckTextChange()
})

function CheckTextChange() {

    $('.txt').each(function () {

        if ($(this).val() == $(this).prop("defaultValue")) {

            alert($(this).val() + ' == ' + $(this).prop("defaultValue"));

        } else {

            alert($(this).val() + ' != ' + $(this).prop("defaultValue"));

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This is correct. Your scoping of `this` in your case is referring to window scope vs your jQuery object. Notice that inside of the `.each()` you can use this and it referrers to a jQuery object. As a fun test for scoping checkout this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6ymxw4mg/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JQuery change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event to track which one of the text boxes is being changed. You have several  having same class attribute. In the answer the **(function(){..})()** is called [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) . This is very impotant if you want your variables not to expose into global scope. Example : **var IsChanged** would get global and other pages may change it's value

```
 (function(){

       var IsChanged = false;
       $('#btnClick').on("click",function() {
        if(IsChanged)
        console.log('Changed');
        else
        console.log('Not changed';)
    });

      $('.txt').change(function(){
        IsChanged = true;
      });

    })();
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Comment: I have added some explanation. Hope it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if any value have changed:

```
function CheckTextChange () {
   var rtrn = false;
   $('.txt').each(function() {     
       var previousVal = $(this)[0].defaultValue, currentVal = $(this).val();
       if (currentVal != previousVal) {          
           rtrn = true || rtrn;
       } 
   }) ;
return rtrn;    
}
```